# Linear Algebra question simple proof regarding invertibility

Tags: linear-algebra

If $X, Y, Z$ are invertible matrices and $X = (X+Y)Z$,

How would we prove $X+Y$ is also invertible?

Answer (score 6):

$$X Z^{-1} = (X + Y)$$

$$I = (Z X^{-1}) (X Z^{-1}) = (Z X^{-1}) (X + Y)$$

So

$$(X + Y)^{-1} = Z X^{-1}$$

Answer (score 3):

yet another approach,

$rank(AB)\leq min\{rank(B),rank(A)\}$

Comment: Great! ..... +1